# Changing test set of an existing test case in Rally using Ext Js

Tags: extjs, rally

I want to create a report where where we have capability to reparent our test cases from one test set to other.

in simple language, I need to remove the existing link with the test set and assign a new test set for my existing test case/cases.

I was referring to one existing report at https://github.com/RallyTechServices/test-picker/blob/master/deploy/App.html

```
 listeners: {
                            scope: this,
                            artifactChosen: function(items){
                                Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore',{
                                    model:'TestSet',
                                    pageSize: 1,
                                    autoLoad: true,
                                    filters: [{property:'ObjectID',value:record.get('ObjectID')}],
                                    listeners: {
                                        load: function(store,records){
                                        console.dir(records.length);
                                            var ts = records[0];

                                            me._log(["Selected items:",items]);
                                            var tc_store = ts.getCollection('TestCases');
                                            me._log(["Got store:",tc_store]);
                                            tc_store.add(items);
                                            me._log("Added items.");
                                            tc_store.sync({
            //                                    callback: function(){
            //                                        me._log("inside callback");
            //                                        me._getTestSets(me.iteration_selector.getValue());
            //                                    }
                                                success: function(batch,options) {
                                                    me._getTestSets(me.iteration_selector.getValue());
                                                },
                                                failure: function(batch,options) {
                                                    me._getTestSets(me.iteration_selector.getValue());
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
```

Here If I try to use remove it gives me an error, I am not sure what is causing the issue.
Or How can I approach the issue. I need to change the test set of any user selected test case in my report. Can please some help me on the same.

The error is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRef' of null". When it can add to the same object why cant it delete. I understand that it has only one value. but I tried removing the filters as well from code snippet mentioned below, but still it gives only current selected test case object id.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can someone please help me on this.